# R package for IRT with planned missing data/multiple forms

Tags: r, missing-data

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions for an R package that can do IRT with planned missing data/multiple forms designs? I have previously analyzed this sort of data in Bilog-MG, but would like to use R if possible.

Here's the situation. I have a bank of 51 items that were spread into 4 forms of 35 each. There were linking items that were common across all forms. However, the total possible score would be 35 (if just summing raw scores).

I have analyzed in MIRT, but I'm concerned that the missing items are treated as 0 primarily because when I look at the plot of the expected total score to theta the max for the total score is 51, not 35.  When I previously analyzed similar data (only 2 forms at that time), the expected total score to theta had a max of 35.

Thoughts on an equivalent package in R or am I missing something in MIRT (totally possible) or do I need to bite the bullet and repurchase Bilog?

Comment: Such "tool request" questions are not usually well-received on this site and are usually closed. For what it's worth, there are a lot of R packages related to psychometrics: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html

Comment: I don't think that the missing items have been treated as 0 in the process of parameter estimation. That the max total score is 51 either sounds like a bug in mirt or some kind of mistake in the data. Anyways would be a topic for the support of mirt https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/issues?q=is%3Aopen. As an alternative R package for IRT analyses you can have a look at TAM.

Answer (score 0):

In case you (1) want to apply a model without slope parameters (i.e., RM, PCM, RSM and their linear decompositions), and (2) items overlap between forms, you might consider the eRm package. It employs CML and handles the planned missings. Otherwise, you probably have to perform equating (maybe Kolen & Brennan (2004), Test Equating, Scaling, and Linking, Springer can help). You may also look into the TAM package.